# Do chrome extensions clear their cookies on autoupdate?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I have implemented cookie-based authentication in a chrome extension. However, it seems that whenever the extension is autoupdated, my cookie authentication fails and I have to re-log in to the extension. Is this expected behavior? My extension seems to be clearing all of the cookies whenever the extension is updated, forcing a re-login.

Comment: It means your code does that.

Comment: so no default behavior behind this?

Comment: There is none. Extensions don't have their own cookies in the first place so you're talking about something your code implements. Without seeing your code the only other idea is that it's a bug or an inherent limitation of extensions.